# Can not select curves control points

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to select two ending control points on a curve in order to scale them, however, blender doesn't let me do it like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqWYgrXw7Jk

Deselecting handler instantly if I unselect middle point:
https://youtu.be/6Jh8ByXiRBU

Any fixes?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

And as always, I have found the solution the moment after posting, this site is magical! The way to deselect this middle point is by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd>.

Comment: Another way you could have scaled them although the center points are selected would have been to change the _Transform Pivot Point_ to _Individual Origins_ instead of the default _Median Point_ (actually, the Ctrl+LMB doesn't work for me when I'm trying to do it on more than one center point).